# Merged and pushed feature branch to the wrong remote branch. How to fix?

Tags: git

A local branch:-

> 1. 'feature/100'

And Remote branches:-

> 1. 'master'
> 2. 'Version2'

Accidently, I have merged my feature branch '**feature/100**' to the **master** and also **pushed** it to the remote repository.

Whereas the feature branch '**feature/100**' should have been merged into remote branch '**Version2**'.

How should i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git revert -m1 <commit id of the merge>`. Where `1` is a parent number of the merge (so that which of the merge parents should be reverted). I assume it is `1` by default, but it rarely could be `2`.

More info: http://git-scm.com/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html

Comment: Not really any default about it. `1` is the checked-out branch, the merge commit's first parent, `2` is the branch merged, the merge's second parent. It's the difference between `HEAD^1` and `HEAD^2`.

Comment: Thanks for the link to undoing-merges.html.  A very worth while read on the nuances of `revert`!